# CSV reader behavior with None and empty string

Tags: python, csv, string, nonetype

I'd like to distinguish between `None` and empty strings (`''`) when going back and forth between Python data structure and csv representation using Python's `csv` module.

My issue is that when I run:

```
import csv, cStringIO

data = [['NULL/None value',None],
        ['empty string','']]

f = cStringIO.StringIO()
csv.writer(f).writerows(data)

f = cStringIO.StringIO(f.getvalue())
data2 = [e for e in csv.reader(f)]

print "input : ", data
print "output: ", data2
```

I get the following output:

```
input :  [['NULL/None value', None], ['empty string', '']]
output:  [['NULL/None value', ''], ['empty string', '']]
```

Of course, I could play with `data` and `data2` to distinguish `None` and empty strings with things like:

```
data = [d if d!=None else 'None' for d in data]
data2 = [d if d!='None' else None for d in data2]
```

But that would partly defeat my interest of the `csv` module (quick deserialization/serialization implemented in C, specially when you are dealing with large lists).

Is there a `csv.Dialect` or parameters to `csv.writer` and `csv.reader` that would enable them to distinguish between `''` and `None` in this use-case?

If not, would there be an interest in implementing a patch to `csv.writer` to enable this kind of back and forth? (Possibly a `Dialect.None_translate_to` parameter defaulting to `''` to ensure backward compatibility.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer) suggests that what you want is not possible:

> To make it as easy as possible to interface with modules which implement the DB API, the value None is written as the empty string.

This is in the documentation for the `writer` class, suggesting it is true for all dialects and is an intrinsic limitation of the csv module.

I for one would support changing this (along with various other limitations of the csv module), but it may be that people would want to offload this sort of work into a different library, and keep the CSV module simple (or at least as simple as it is).

If you need more powerful file-reading capabilities, you might want to look at the CSV reading functions in numpy, scipy, and pandas, which as I recall have more options.

Comment: Yep confirmed : looking at csv_writerow in Modules/_csv.c ( if (field == Py_None) ... ). There is no way to distinguish between a '' and a None. Really a shame, given the Dialect abstraction you would have hoped for a bit more flexibility. You mention other limitations of the csv module, would you mind elaborating (If there are other issues I really should start looking at other csv-reading writing) ?

Comment: One limitation I've found annoying sometimes is that delimiters must be a single character.  So you can't parse a file where columns are separated by, say, two tabs.  Like the None thing you came across, this is fairly easy to work around, but still annoying.

Comment: Another is the hard coded ascii limitation within the module.

Answer (score 18):

You could at least partially side-step what the `csv` module does by creating your own version of a singleton `None`-like class/value:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv


class NONE(object):
    ''' None-like class. '''
    def __repr__(self): # Method csv.writer class uses to write values.
        return 'NONE'   # Unique string value to represent None.
    def __len__(self):  # Method called to determine length and truthiness.
        return 0

NONE = NONE()  # Singleton instance of the class.


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        from cStringIO import StringIO  # Python 2.
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        from io import StringIO  # Python 3.

    data = [['None value', None], ['NONE value', NONE], ['empty string', '']]
    f = StringIO()
    csv.writer(f).writerows(data)

    f = StringIO(f.getvalue())
    print(" input:", data)
    print("output:", [e for e in csv.reader(f)])
```

Results:

```
 input: [['None value', None], ['NONE value', NONE],   ['empty string', '']]
output: [['None value', ''],   ['NONE value', 'NONE'], ['empty string', '']]
```

Using `NONE` instead of `None` would preserve enough information for you to be able to differentiate between it and any actual empty-string data values.

#### Even better alternative…

You could use the same approach to implement a pair of relatively lightweight `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` “proxy” classes — necessary since you can't actually subclass the built-in `csv` classes which are written in C — without introducing a lot of overhead (since the majority of the processing would still be performed by the underlying built-ins). This would make what goes on completely transparent since it's all encapsulated within the proxies.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv


class csvProxyBase(object): _NONE = '<None>'  # Unique value representing None.


class csvWriter(csvProxyBase):
    def __init__(self, csvfile, *args, **kwrags):
        self.writer = csv.writer(csvfile, *args, **kwrags)
    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([self._NONE if val is None else val for val in row])
    def writerows(self, rows):
        list(map(self.writerow, rows))


class csvReader(csvProxyBase):
    def __init__(self, csvfile, *args, **kwrags):
        self.reader = csv.reader(csvfile, *args, **kwrags)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        return [None if val == self._NONE else val for val in next(self.reader)]
    next = __next__  # Python2.x compatibility.


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        from cStringIO import StringIO  # Python 2.
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        from io import StringIO  # Python 3.

    data = [['None value', None], ['empty string', '']]
    f = StringIO()
    csvWriter(f).writerows(data)

    f = StringIO(f.getvalue())
    print("input : ", data)
    print("ouput : ", [e for e in csvReader(f)])
```

Results:

```
 input: [['None value', None], ['empty string', '']]
output: [['None value', None], ['empty string', '']]
```

Comment: A variation of the first solution solved the write problem for me. Created a class NONE(int) with a __repr__ which returns an empty string. Replaced all None values with NONE (I had to format my data anyway so was no extra work). Then create the csv writer with QUOTE_NONNUMERIC.

This is a bit hacky, but it means that in the output file you know that a quoted field is always a string, and an unquoted empty field is always a None.

Comment: @trelltron: Clever, but a potential downside is that it _requires_ the use of `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` which you may not want otherwise and has the potential the make the files much larger. My solution(s) don't require using any particular `csv` options in order to work. Also note that my second alternative doesn't require replacing all `None` values with anything.

Answer (score 2):

As you have control over both the consumer and the creator of the serialised data, consider using a format that does support that distinction.

Example:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['foo', '', None, 666])
'["foo", "", null, 666]'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be possible to do what you want with a mere dialect, but you could write your own csv.reader/write subclass. On the other hand, I still think that is overkill for this use case. Even if you want to catch more than just `None`, you probably just want `str()`:

```
>>> data = [['NULL/None value',None],['empty string','']]
>>> i = cStringIO.StringIO()
>>> csv.writer(i).writerows(map(str,row) for row in data)
>>> print i.getvalue()
NULL/None value,None
empty string,
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, this is a limitation of the `csv` module. A solution is just to rewrite the rows inside a loop with a simple dictionary comprehension, as follows:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    # Interpret empty values as None (instead of '')
    row = {k: v if v else None for k, v in row.items()}
    :
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you can't really do this via `csv.Dialect` or parameters to `csv.writer` and/or `csv.reader`. However as I said in one comment, you implement it by *effectively* subclassing the latter two (you apparently can't really do because they're built-in). What the "subclasses" do on writing is simply intercept `None` values and change them into a unique string and reverse the process when reading them back in. Here's a fully worked-out example:

```
import csv, cStringIO
NULL = '<NULL>'  # something unlikely to ever appear as a regular value in your csv files

class MyCsvWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwrds):
        self.csv_writer = csv.writer(*args, **kwrds)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.csv_writer, name)

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.csv_writer.writerow([item if item is not None else NULL
                                      for item in row])
    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

class MyCsvReader(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwrds):
        self.csv_reader = csv.reader(*args, **kwrds)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.csv_reader, name)

    def __iter__(self):
        rows = iter(self.csv_reader)
        for row in rows:
            yield [item if item != NULL else None for item in row]

data = [['NULL/None value', None],
        ['empty string', '']]

f = cStringIO.StringIO()
MyCsvWriter(f).writerows(data)  # instead of csv.writer(f).writerows(data)

f = cStringIO.StringIO(f.getvalue())
data2 = [e for e in MyCsvReader(f)]  # instead of [e for e in csv.reader(f)]

print "input : ", data
print "ouput : ", data2
```

Output:

```
input :  [['NULL/None value', None], ['empty string', '']]
ouput :  [['NULL/None value', None], ['empty string', '']]
```

It's a tad verbose and probably slows the reading & writing of csv file a bit (since they're written in C/C++) but that may make little difference since the process is likely low-level I/O bound anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem too and find this https://bugs.python.org/issue23041.

Solutions from the issue:

> - subclass csv.DictWriter, use dictionaries as your element type, and have its writerow method do the application-specific work.
> - define a writerow() function which does something similar (essentially wrapping csv.writerow()).