# Preserve null when reading csv file in Python and sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, csv, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python csv reader behavior with None and empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379300/python-csv-reader-behavior-with-none-and-empty-string)

When reading in a csv file, the reader reads `None` or `NULL` as `(u'')`. This is causing me problems when inserting values into a sqlite database and performing queries as all null values are stored as empty strings. Is there a way of using the reader to insert nulls? What I have so far is:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filename))
curs.executemany("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?,?,?,?)", reader)
```

Comment: Ah, it's a real shame that the functionality is this limited.

Comment: I don't think it's limited. I've always thought that `null` in a database instead of the empty string for `VARCHAR`/`TEXT` is annoying. Maybe you should change your schema to use `DEFAULT ''`.