# Python: write CSV with QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, except for None

Tags: python, r, csv, readr

Given the data `['a', '', None, 5]` I would like to write a CSV file as:

```
"a","",,5
```

If I use `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, as in:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    spamwriter.writerow(['a', None, 5])
```

I get

```
"a","","",5
```

but if I remove the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, I get the unquoted empty string from `Nona`, but I also lose the quotes around the `a` and the empty string.

```
a,,,5
```

Context: I want to write files that can be read using R readr r: `read_csv('eggs.csv', na=c(""), quoted_na=FALSE)` that can distinguish between the empty string and missing data.

Comment: It seems like it is not possible with `csv` module per answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379300/csv-reader-behavior-with-none-and-empty-string), which is coming from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a variation of the answer (and comment) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11380084/1319998, you can replace `None` in the data with an instance of:

```
class EmptyString(int):
    def __str__(self):
        return ''
```

then this will be output by Python's `csv.writer`, using `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` as an unquoted empty string. A fuller example:

```
import csv

class EmptyString(int):
    def __str__(self):
        return ''
EmptyString = EmptyString()

def replace_none_with_emptystring(row):
  return [
    val if val is not None else EmptyString
    for val in row
  ]

with open('eggs.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    spamwriter.writerow(replace_none_with_emptystring(['a', '', None, 5]))
```

saves

```
"a","",,5
```