# Having difficulties extending a class from an imported library (python-pptx)

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-3.6, python-pptx

Setup:

- Python 3.6
- `python-pptx`
- `openpyxl`
- `openpyxl-image-loader`

My goal:
To extend the Presentation class to include more functions to build unique PPT slides
I do not wish to override any previous `__init__()`.

My Progress so far:
I use `type()` to see what class I should extend.

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs=Presentation('template.pptx')
print(type(prs))
>><class 'pptx.presentation.Presentation'>
```

I then created a new class that inherits `pptx.presentation.Presentation`:

```
class Build_ppt(pptx.presentation.Presentation):

   def build_cover(self,i,ws):
   #i : index
   #ws: is an openpyxl instance
       pass
```

I then try to call the new `Build_ppt` class similar to how you would `Presentation`:

```
prs=Build_ppt('template.pptx')
```

I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'part'
```

or sometimes it does go through but the super class does not have the proper arguments passed in.

Comment: It's fairly common to not be able to extend classes in modules, especially those written in other languages like C/C++. One workaround it to define a "proxy" class that *has* an instance of the class to be extended in it rather than being derived from one. The methods of the proxy class delegate calls to this instance possibly with so pre- and/or post-processing. There's a trivial example of one in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11380084/355230) to an different question. Also see Wikipedia's [Proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) article.

Answer (score 0):

The `Presentation` object you get with `from pptx import Presentation` is not the same as `pptx.presentation.Presentation`.

If you look in `pptx/__init__.py` you can see `from pptx.api import Presentation`. This is what establishes what you reference as `pptx.Presentation`. https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/__init__.py#L14

If you look in `pptx/api.py` you can see that `Presentation` is a *function* that does the needful to open a presentation (.pptx) document, create a `pptx.presentation.Presentation` object with it, and return that object. https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/api.py#L18

So `pptx.Presentation` looks and acts like a class, but it isn't. If you want your own version of `pptx.Presentation` you'll have to model it after the `pptx.api.Presentation` function rather than the object it returns.

However, I don't recommend you do that. There are a lot of complexities and you'll be completely on your own because everything you do from there on is in "off-label" territory and not using the published interfaces.

What you can do instead is *compose* a `Presentation` object and then manipulate it with the class that "contains" it.

The other alternative is to *fork* `python-pptx` and extend it to suit your purposes. Of course you're on your own that way as well.

A third alternative is to use `python-pptx` as it is for whatever you can and write "extension" functions that do things `python-pptx` can't directly do for you. This is a very common approach and one I use myself fairly often.